# authentication in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have a web.config with

```
<location path="MyFolder"> 
<system.web> 
<authorization> 
<allow users="MySiteUsers" /> 
</authorization> 
</system.web> 
</location>
```

My question is, where should I define "MySiteUsers" role ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `MySiteUsers` role in the membership storage of whatever [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) role provider [you have chosen to use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b241xwt.aspx).

You can [implement your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx) if wanted, but one of the most common options is the SQL Server - you can easily set this up using [`aspnet_regsql.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

According to your config, you are granting permission to a particular user "MySiteUsers", you'll then need a Membership provider. It could be as simple as defining a user in your web.config file or AspNetMembership provider etc.
This is different from roles really, so if you want a role, you will need the implementation of a RoleProvider and change users to roles.